# Ubuntu won't run on Toshiba NB550D

Tags: toshiba

I get a message about manually having to configure video or running at lo resolution, but I'm not able to get to the desktop, even at lo resolution...

Messages: "Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself."

"*Run in low-graphics mode for just one session
*Reconfigure graphics
*troubleshoot the error
*Exit to console login"

I choose the first option and get

"Stand by one minute while the display restarts."

I hit ok to that and then get a black screen with a flashing curser in top left corner,
no disc activity. I waited for 10+ minutes..